Conduché fibrations
Given the following definition
Defn: Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a category with finite limits. An object $Y$ of $\mathcal{A}$ is called exponentiable if the functor $(- \times Y) \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A}$ has a right adjoint, denoted by $( )^Y$ . A morphism is called
exponentiable if it is exponentiable in $\mathcal{A}/Y$.
So the functor $(- \times Y) \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A}$ is defined by  $$ (B \to B') \mapsto (B \times Y \longrightarrow B' \times Y)$$.
I am trying to prove the result:
A functor $p \colon E \to B$ between small categories is exponential as an object of $\mathbf{Cat}/B$ if and only if it is a Conduché fibration.
I know that exponentiability in $\mathbf{Cat}$ for objects, is actually a functor category. Since objects in the category $\mathbf{Cat}/B$ would be functors with codomain $B$, this is somewhat tricky for me, is it correct to show that such functors are exponentiable in $\mathbf{Cat}$?
This question is a Theorem in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Conduch%C3%A9+functor

What do you mean by "exponentiable in $\mathbf{Cat}$ as morphisms with codomain $B$", if it's not "exponentiable in $\mathbf{Cat}/B$"?

The theorem in the link is has stated it differently. Instead the equivalent condition for $p$ to be a Conduche fibration is that $p$ is exponential in $\mathbf{Cat}$. I think its okay to say it as just in the theorem instead. I will edit and remove "as morphisms..."

I really don't understand what you mean. nLab says: "A Conduché functor […] is a functor which is an exponentiable morphism in Cat.". By definition, this means an exponentiable object in Cat/B. What else could it possibly mean?

I am not familiar with exponentiability. Thank you

Do you know where I can find the proof of the theorem?

See the references at the bottom of the linked nLab page. It's lemma 6.1 in Fibrations and partial products in a 2-category.

The nLab is currently incorrect. Lemma 6.1 only contains a proof of one direction.

However, Street's note Powerful functors does appear to contain a complete proof.
